# How do I disable easymotion in terminal mode?

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer, original-vim, plugin-easymotion

I'm using easymotion with all buffers and it works well but changing to terminal mode raises the issue.

[image]

Thus I want to disable it in terminal mode for convenient.

How can I do it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on how you load the plugin, but as far as I know, there isn't a way to disable a plugin once its loaded. This error occurs because the vim terminal cannot be modified, but easymotion needs to modify the terminal buffer to work. This was fixed in neovim terminals (see https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion/issues/246), but not in vim.